# Building Java Tree

Tags: java, tree

can anyone provide me a link to build a tree structure (which can have multiple childrens) in java.

Comment: I think hash map will be helpful here.. but don't know exactly how can I use it

Comment: No you can think it as in terms of database like it contain table with employee id and its manager id, (rememeber manger is also employee and CEO manger id is NULL). Now I have to create a tree from that table

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: @bidhutkarki I think you posted the same question yesterday. What is your input? What do you expect as output? This is a simple task in principle, all you need is a class Employee which also has an Employee field (its manager). You don't need employee nodes and all that. Your question is more of a modeling question than a coding question btw (not that this is bad IMHO).

Comment: What you mean with Node here? What you except as output? And why ID and ManagerID are strings?

Comment: You briefly mentioned that this is for a database. Then I suggest you get the SQL right first and then worry about the Java. The most efficient way to do it is with one SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a model like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Employee {

    private String id;

    private Employee manager;

    private List<Employee> directReports;

    public Employee(String id){
        this.id = id;
        this.directReports = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Employee getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setManager(Employee manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public List<Employee> getDirectReports() {
        return directReports;
    }

    public void setDirectReports(List<Employee> directReports) {
        this.directReports = directReports;
    }

}
```

Here you definitely need the **manager** field as it gives who is the manager 
of this Employee. The **directReports** field is optional, you leave it in
only if you want to model your relation as a bidirectional one i.e.
if you want each Employee to also know which Employees report
to him/her (meaning this Employee is a manager of his/her direct reports).

Now based on whatever input you have just build the right set of Employee
objects and make sure they are interrelated in the proper way (using
the **manager** and the **directReports** fields). This is what I would suggest.

Create also some factory class which creates Employee instances
(this factory class can be the Employee class itself).
Before creating an Employee with a given id make sure you
do a lookup first to see if it exists. And if it exists, just reuse 
it instead of creating a new one (as you don't want to have two or
 
more Employee instances with the same id).